# The principal branch of the logarithm. Find the range of θ .

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{x=y\geq 0\}$.

Find $log_\Omega(re^{i\theta})$.

I am new with branch of the logarithm.

I can't get why $\theta\in (\frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}) = (\frac{-7\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$.

[image]

I don't get how to approach this problem.

Why $\frac{\pi}{3}$ doesnt work here ? Thanks.

Comment: It's desired for the domain to have an interval of values of $\theta$. Any interval that contains, say, zero and $\pi/3$ will also contain $\pi/4$ which is the branch cut $x=y\ge0$, where we are not meant to define the logarithm.

Comment: Understood, Algo?

Comment: Yes thanks @GerryMyerson